# Node MongoDB connection read-only without creating an user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to create a mongoDB read-only connection without creating a user (which violates idea of read-only in my view)?

I tried the code below, but it's still possible to write to db.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/Example?readOnly=true&readPreference=secondary';

const client = MongoClient.connect(uri);
```

How to enforce `readOnly=true` part of the code above?

Comment: Connect to a secondary node.

Answer (score 0):

> which violates idea of read-only in my view

"read-only" has a scope. A user can have read permissions only. Some systems may in theory allow a connection to be read-only.

If a system is "read-only" regardless of scope (if the scope is infinitely expanded), it cannot have any data at all (since initially a system generally has no data) and it is thus completely useless in practice.

You are essentially talking about the read equivalent of [write only memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke)).

Comment: I ask about read-only connection not memory? I want to connect to external mongodb and make sure nothing is written to database.

Comment: Right. Create a user that only has roles that have only read privileges. Use this user to connect.